# Gps python 2 program crashs bash file execution, raspberry pi

Tags: bash, python-2.7, python-3.x, gps, raspberry-pi

I have recently encountered a problem with executing python scripts on the Raspberry Pi using bash files. I have two programs, the first need not be mentioned as there are no problems running it. The second however reads GPS data from my USB GPS receiver and once it has been executed from a bash file based in the terminal it ends the running of the infinite loop bash file. It is in python 2 and the first program is in python 3. I cannot combine them into one program as the GPS program is not supported in python 3 due to modules not being updated. The code for the GPS program can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wolfg1969/4653340).

The only difference my code has is that I use a while loop to make it execute 10 times instead of infinitely. I want to prevent this program ending the bash file prematurely so it runs infinitely. I've tried running the bash file from another bash file so if a crash happens the script would be restarted but it seems that the terminal no longer takes any inputs after the GPS program has finished executing. Any help on this would be appreciated greatly! 
My bash file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    echo "Running programs"
    sh ./programtimer.sh 
    sleep 20 
done
```

`programtimer.sh` simply runs the two python programs, the GPS program being run second.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  First, change `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash` and `sh` to `bash`.  If your scripts use bash-specific features, trying to run them under `sh` will fail.  Second, if you can roll everything into one script, you'll probably have an easier time debugging.  Third, would you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41915647/edit) to clarify?  You mention `programmer.sh` and `programtimer.sh`.  Is that a typo?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what the issue you're seeing is. You mention that "it seems that the terminal no longer takes any inputs after the GPS program has finished executing", but this seems normal. Your outer-most bash script is still running with a while loop; you should see no output for twenty seconds, and then it should re-run programmer.sh again.

Comment: My problem is that after it finished the inner script that after 20 seconds it no longer restarts, and yes I did have an error, I will correct that.

Comment: I think the problem lies in how the python 2 GPS program has been run, it is using threads and a class, it executed perfectly.in it's own but after executing it using a bash script the bash script no longer runs, that isn't the case with the other program being called in the script as it still runs after executing that program.